# 3 coloring of vertices in a graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory

How can we prove that there exists a coloring of vertices for graph $G$ such that at least 2/9 fraction of all triangles in $G$ whose vertices have different colors?

Comment: I would consider rephrasing your command into a question, as you are asking the other users a favor, not giving us an assignment.

Comment: Sorry, just did that, hope it is what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color the graph randomly, the probability that a triangle whose vertices have different colors is $\frac{3 \times 2}{3 \times 3 \times 3}=\frac{2}{9}$. Let $X_{t}$ be the indicator random variable that $t$ has distinct colors, then $E[X_{t}]=\frac{2}{9}$. Let $T$ be the set of all triangles and $X=\sum_{t \in T}X_{t}$, by linearity of expectation, the expected number of triangles is $E[X]=\sum_{t \in T}E[X_{t}]=\frac{2}{9}|T|$. By probabilistic method, there exists a coloring that at least $\frac{2}{9}$ of triangles receive 3 distinct colors.

Comment: That's a step forward, but your proof is incomplete.  (Note: the events "triangle X is assigned 3 distinct colours" and "triangle Y is assigned 3 distinct colours" might not be independent.)

Comment: You are right. Do you know how to continue?

Comment: Find the expected proportion of triangles that have 3 distinct colours.  Then use the probabilistic method.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified the proof.

Comment: Another step forward, but still not finished.  You've shown that the average number of triangles that receive 3 distinct colours is 2/9.  You now need to show that this implies there exists a colouring in which the proportion of triangles that receive 3 distinct colours is 2/9.  This is where you use the magic of the [probabilistic method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method)!  (PS. If I were marking this, I would take off marks for not citing the use of "[linearity of expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity)".)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I updated the answer. Thanks for your time!